# When does kubernetes helm trigger a pod recreate?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

The [helm documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/) suggests to **recreate a pod** by setting variable metadata values.

For example:

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
[...]
```

But there a **situations**, when a pod is **not** recreated:

- A pod is erroneous in state `CrashLoopBackOff`
- Only Deployment Metadata has changed

I would like to know **what events** do trigger a pod recreate:

- Why is the pod in state `CrashLoopBackOff` not restarted?
- Why are not all parts of the spec considered to recreate the pod?

**Edit**

The `CrashLookBackOff` is an application problem.
But if a new image (containing the bugfix) is provided, the pod should be restarted without the need to kill it explicitly.

Is there a cause not to restart the `CrashLookBackOff` pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *template* in a `Deployment` is a `PodTemplate`. Every time the PodTemplate is changed, a new ReplicaSet is created, and it creates new Pods according to the number of replicas using the PodTemplate.

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    # any change here will lead to new Pods
```

Everytime a new Pod is created from a template, it will be identical as the previous pods.

A `CrashLoopBackOff` is a Pod-level problem, e.g. it may be a problem with the application.

> But if a new image (containing the bugfix) is provided, the pod should be restarted without the need to kill it explicitly.

If a new image is provided, it should have its own unique name. That means that whenever you change the image, you have to change the image name. A change of the image name is a change in the PodTemplate, so it will always create new Pods - and delete but not reuse old Pods.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply, which answered the template question! I've edited my question for the CrashLoopBackOff part. This is still not clear for me.

Comment: I expanded my answer on that part.

Comment: You're right: When I provide an image with a new version, the CrashLoopBackOff pod is restarted.