# Best practises for helm kubernetes deployment pipeline in a development environment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

These are the best practises for a helm deployment which I figured out so far:

1. Use versioned images, because deploying via latest tag is not sufficient, as this may not trigger a pod recreate (see [When does kubernetes helm trigger a pod recreate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64290972/when-does-kubernetes-helm-trigger-a-pod-recreate/64291282)).
2. Use hashed configmap metadata to restart pods on configmap changes
   (see https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/)

In a development environment new images are created often. Because I don't want to trash my container registry, I'd prefer using latest tags.

The only solution - I can think of - is to use versioned imaged and a cleanup job to remove old image from the registry. But this is quite complicated.

So what are your best practises for helm deployments in a development environment?

Comment: I think it's good to rename the subject, to it will reflect question about images, using latest tag and doing the cleanup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, using `:latest` will mean that your deployments will be mutable.

AWS ECR allows you to keep limited number of latest images according to certain regex. So you can use `dev-` prefix for your non-production deployments (for example triggered outside of `master` branch) and keep only 10 latest of them.

Comment: Unfortunately azure (which I'm using in my current project) does not have a policy with regex. But for AWS this is of course a good thing. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like there are ways to script deletion of old images also in Azure, take a look: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/container-registry/container-registry-delete.md

Comment: The script looks promising. I will check this, thanks!